# Kotlin type mismatch when using RxJava retryWhen operator

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying create Observable, which will retryWhen when the network connection will be established.

I've created subject:

```
 private val retrySubject = PublishSubject.create<Unit>()()
```

And I am using it like this:

```
  private fun publishNetworkReconnection() {
    compositeDisposable?.add(
       connectionHelper.observeConnection()
        .subscribe {connected: Boolean
          if(connected){
          retrySubject.onNext(null)
          }
        }
     )
  }
```

Then I am trying to use it in my retryWhen operator:

```
   val disposable =
    Flowable.interval(0, UPDATE_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
        .onBackpressureDrop()
        .flatMapCompletable {
          revocationRepository.sync(event.id)
        }
        .retryWhen { retryHandler -> retryHandler.flatMap({ nothing -> retrySubject.asObservable() }) }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({ }, { Timber.e(it, "Unable to sync blacklist") })
    compositeDisposable?.add(disposable)
  }
```

How to use it properly in this case?

I am getting this error in Android Studio:

> Type mismatch. Required: Publisher<< out (???..???) >>! Found: Observable<
>   Void
>   !>!

Comment: Do you use RxJava 1 or 2? On one hand you have `Flowable`, on the other hand, `Subject.asObservable` which was in RxJava 1. Are you using both versions? It's hard to even compile this code

Comment: @michalbrz I was following this example https://android.jlelse.eu/rx-grokking-retrywhen-and-repeatwhen-on-android-development-examples-af5c3ed0872b

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, you are mixing RxJava 1 - [`Subject.asObservable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#asObservable--) and RxJava 2 - [`Flowable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html).

The signature of [`retryWhen`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#retryWhen-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) from RxJava 2 is:

```
Flowable<T> retryWhen(Function<? super Flowable<Throwable>,? extends Publisher<?>> handler)
```

so lambda inside `retryWhen` should return something that extends `Publisher`. Instead, you are returning `Subject<Unit>` which is converted to `Observable<Void>`, because apparently your `Subject` is from RxJava 1. And - because of RxJava version difference - obviously it doesn't extend `Publisher`.

So error message is correct, `retryWhen` expects `Publisher` from **RxJava 2**, but you give `Obervable` from **RxJava 1**. You didn't notice different packages, because they are not included in message.

The main issue is mixing code from RxJava 1 and RxJava 2 which is never good.

Comment: So, what will be the correct expression for `retryWhen` in RxJava 2?

Comment: @anshul I'm not sure if it helps you, here is the code I'm using - https://gist.github.com/vkotovv/a75490988e4c544d108b5e738922988f

Comment: @VadimKotov no it did not help. Here is my exact problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59856216/retrywhen-is-giving-some-issues-when-using-with-single