# RetryWhen is giving some issues when using with Single

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to hit an API call using retrofit and receive the response from the call. I am using the Single of Rxjava to get the response. What I need to do is that a retry if the call fails.
I have gone through lots of examples but it seems none could have been a help (Also because of my limited knowledge on RXjava and Kotlin).

Below is the function which does the call and the `retryWhen` function I wrote

```
fun testFetch(): Single<ResponseBody>{
    return retrofitService.getCTLNetworkService().test().retryWhen {
        val ato = AtomicInteger()
        it.takeWhile {
            ato.incrementAndGet() < 4
        }.flatMap {
            Flowable.timer(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        }
    }
}
```

This is exactly what I want to achieve

```
  Single.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
 *     .doOnSubscribe(s -&gt; System.out.println("subscribing"))
 *     .map(v -&gt; { throw new RuntimeException(); })
 *     .retryWhen(errors -&gt; {
 *         AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
 *         return errors
 *                   .takeWhile(e -&gt; counter.getAndIncrement() != 3)
 *                   .flatMap(e -&gt; {
 *                       System.out.println("delay retry by " + counter.get() + " second(s)");
 *                       return Flowable.timer(counter.get(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 *                   });
 *     })
 *     .blockingGet();
```

Below is the error when I compile the code

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is (Throwable!) -> Flowable<Long!>! but ((Throwable!) -> Publisher!)! was expected
```

**NOTE: Changed the method for simplicity. Even a simple `signle<ResponseBody>` call without any mapper and model fails**

Comment: Please edit your post and add your mapper/model classes too. I've tried to recreate a sample using your code, and it compiles fine

Comment: retrwhen only work with Observable. For single there is no way for resubscribe so it will not work with single.

Answer (score 0):

check this [Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/vamjakuldip/08f676af58dc590ed28be96d658472c0)

Here is example how to use extension

```
// import extension file 
import com.vk.extension.retryWhenError
 // example
 Observable.fromIterable<Int>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)).retryWhen { it.retryWhenError()}
        .subscribe { integers: Int -> Log.d(TAG, "item $integers") }
```

Comment: I don't agree. If that is the case then why did Single class of Rxjava has given an example in it's retryWhen method